# nonSQL related attribute add to SQLAlchemy model error

Tags: python, postgresql, class, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm developing a web app with python and flask. I use Flask, SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL for development. I have many-to-one related models. By this models one company can have many users but each user can only have one company.

```
models.py
class Company(ResourceMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'companies'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, index=True, 
                     nullable=False, server_default='')
    phone = db.Column(db.String(24)) 
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), index=True)
    address = db.Column(db.String(255))

    # Relations
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='company')

class User(UserMixin, ResourceMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # User details
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(24)) 
    address = db.Column(db.String(255))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False,
                      server_default='')
    password = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False, server_default='')

    # Relations
    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('companies.id', 
                                                     onupdate='CASCADE',
                                                     ondelete='SET NULL'), 
                           index=True)


views.py
app.route('/')
def index():
    company = Company.query.get(1)
    flash(company.name, company.user_count)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Error summary: "user_count" attribute is not part of the Company model.

I want to get the number of the users dynamically from Company model. Attribute should count users on each call of the model and serve it on a regular attribute (like company.user_count). I made it by creating a class method and calling it in view function but i want it to make the process automatic without calling method prior to use attribute.

I tried **init** function like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.user_count = len(self.users)
```

And like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.status()

def status(self):
    self.user_count = len(self.users)
    return True
```

And like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.status()

@classmethod
def status(self):
    self.user_count = len(self.users)
    return True
```

all three versions throws same error. How can i overcome the problem.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a property:

```
class User(Base):
    ...
    @property
    def user_count(self):
        return len(self.users)
```

Comment: Hi! I tried @property and it worked like charm. How i can call attributes directly. But yet there is still a problem. I want to use it to in order_by method. I use `order_by(cast(Company.user_count, Integer))` but it throws `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_children'` error.if i try same code with `Company.id` it works. So new property is somehow different from others. (Note: I also tried @hybrid_property and results are same)

Comment: @CarnageTR Well of course it's different; it's not a real column in SQL! If you need to order by `user_count`, you have three options (in order of performance): 1. use a subquery, i.e. `ORDER BY (SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE users.company_id = companies.id)`; 2. use join and aggregation, e.g. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, count(*) AS cnt FROM companies JOIN users ON users.company_id = companies.id GROUP BY companies.id) subq ORDER BY subq.cnt`; 3. denormalize the `user_count` column and update the count every time you add or remove a user.